# Unable to Click anything (like button) in Card View used in Grid View using Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, button, gridview, cardview

**Here is the Code of MainActivity.kt**

```
//Declarations
lateinit var recyclerView: RecyclerView
lateinit var gridView: GridView
lateinit var gridAdapter: ShopListGridAdapter
lateinit var recyclerAdapter: ShopListRecyclerViewAdapter

val items = ArrayList<ShopList>()

//Initialization in onCreate() method
recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recycler_view)
gridView = findViewById(R.id.grid_view)
recyclerAdapter = ShopListRecyclerViewAdapter(applicationContext, items)
gridAdapter = ShopListGridAdapter(applicationContext, items)

//After adding some items in **items array list**
gridView.adapter = gridAdapter
recyclerView.adapter = recyclerAdapter
recyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this@MainActivity)
```

**Here is the Code of ShopListGridAdapter.kt**

```
class ShopListGridAdapter(var context: Context, var itemList: ArrayList<ShopList>) : BaseAdapter() {

    override fun getCount(): Int = itemList.size
    override fun getItem(position: Int): Any = itemList[position]
    override fun getItemId(position: Int): Long = position.toLong()

    override fun getView(position: Int, convertView: View?, parent: ViewGroup?): View {

        val view: View = View.inflate(context, R.layout.grid_content_item, null)

        ...
        val itemStatusBtn: Button = view.findViewById(R.id.grid_item_status_btn)

        val item: ShopList = itemList[position]
        ...

        itemStatusBtn.setOnClickListener {
            //do stuff
            ...
        }

        return view
    }
}
```

**Here is the XML Code of Grid View (activity_main.xml)**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/ll_wish_list_bar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:paddingVertical="10dp"
            android:paddingHorizontal="20dp"
            android:gravity="center_vertical">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/nav_drawer_opener_iv"
                android:layout_width="25dp"
                android:layout_height="25dp"
                android:src="@drawable/nav_bar_icon"
                android:contentDescription="@string/nav_bar_icon"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/top_bar_tv"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="@string/app_name"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textSize="22sp"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textColor="@color/text_color"/>

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/three_dots_menu_btn"
                android:layout_width="30dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:src="@drawable/more_dots"
                app:tint="@color/text_color"
                android:onClick="openThreeDotsMenu"
                android:contentDescription="@string/change_the_layout"/>

        </LinearLayout>

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/top_curve_rectangle"
            android:paddingTop="25dp">

            <androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
                android:id="@+id/grid_view_swipe_refresh"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

                <GridView
                    android:id="@+id/grid_view"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:paddingBottom="100dp"
                    android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
                    android:verticalSpacing="10dp"
                    android:numColumns="2"
                    android:visibility="invisible"/>

            </androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>

            <androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
                android:id="@+id/recycler_view_swipe_refresh"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

                <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                    android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:paddingBottom="100dp"
                    android:clipToPadding="false"
                    android:visibility="invisible"/>

            </androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>

            <ProgressBar
                android:id="@+id/progress_bar_loading"
                android:layout_width="50dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/add_item_activity_btn"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                android:visibility="visible"/>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/empty_indicator"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:gravity="center"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/add_item_activity_btn"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                android:visibility="invisible"
                tools:ignore="UseCompoundDrawables">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:src="@drawable/shopping_bag"
                    android:contentDescription="@string/empty_shopping_bag"/>

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/your_list_is_empty"
                    android:textSize="30sp"
                    android:textColor="@color/green_color_1"
                    android:fontFamily="@font/roboto_medium"
                    android:textAlignment="center"/>

            </LinearLayout>

            <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
                android:id="@+id/add_item_activity_btn"
                android:layout_width="60dp"
                android:layout_height="60dp"
                android:layout_marginVertical="20dp"
                android:contentDescription="@string/add_item"
                android:src="@drawable/add_icon"
                app:borderWidth="0dp"
                app:maxImageSize="40dp"
                app:tint="@color/white"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                android:onClick="openAddItemActivity"/>

        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

    <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header"
        app:itemIconTint="@color/green_color_1"
        app:itemTextColor="#D93B4043"
        app:itemIconPadding="20dp"
        app:menu="@menu/nav_menu" />

</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

**Here is the code of grid item (grid_content_item.xml)**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingHorizontal="25dp"
    android:paddingVertical="15dp"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/item_name"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/item_name"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="#3FC6BA"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:fontFamily="@font/roboto_bold"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/quantity"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginVertical="5dp"
            android:text="@string/quantity"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:fontFamily="@font/roboto_bold"
            android:textAlignment="center" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/store_location"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/buy_from_anywhere"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:fontFamily="@font/roboto_medium"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/grid_item_status_btn"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:backgroundTint="@color/pending_color"
            android:fontFamily="@font/roboto_bold"
            android:text="@string/pending"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:minHeight="0dip"
            android:textColor="@color/white" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/grid_speak_item_ll"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="20dp"
                android:layout_height="20dp"
                android:src="@drawable/speak_out_icon"
                app:tint="#AB0C5FE8"
                android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
                android:contentDescription="@string/speak_the_item"/>
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/listen"
                android:fontFamily="@font/roboto_bold"
                android:textColor="#AB0C5FE8"/>

        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
```

[Grid View Item](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3mffm.png)

**Other methods tried**

I have also tried this method in MainActivity.kt in onCreate() function

```
gridView.setOnItemClickListener { adapterView, view, pos, id ->
      when(view.id) {
           R.id.grid_item_status_btn -> Toast.makeText(...).show()
      }
}
```

but it also don't work for me. I'm unable to click anything on any item. Why Button is not Clickable? When I'm touching the button, it is not pressable.
If the button gets fixed then I can proceed, but stuck right now. Thanks in Advance

**Changing View Layout in Code**

In onCreate() method

```
sharedPref = getSharedPreferences("settings", MODE_PRIVATE)
if(sharedPref.getInt("view_mode", 0) == 1) gridView.visibility = ViewGroup.VISIBLE
else recyclerView.visibility = ViewGroup.VISIBLE
```

I had added a menu from where I change the view layouts:

```
when (it.itemId) {
      R.id.change_to_grid_view -> changeViewLayout(gridView)
      R.id.change_to_recycler_view -> changeViewLayout(recyclerView)
      ...
}
```

this is the function which handles visibility

```
    private fun changeViewLayout(view: View) {
        if(view == gridView) {
            gridView.visibility = ViewGroup.VISIBLE
            recyclerView.visibility = ViewGroup.INVISIBLE
            gridAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
        } else {
            recyclerView.visibility = ViewGroup.VISIBLE
            gridView.visibility = ViewGroup.INVISIBLE
            recyclerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
        }
    }
```

Means, in my project only one view will be visible at a time. The button in Recycler View is clickable and working everything fine, but not in Grid View.

Comment: can you share `activity_main.xml` layout

Comment: @Zain I have updated the XML code, check it

Comment: Please share the full `grid_content_item.xml` file. something might be overlapping the button.

Comment: I'm doubt that something overlaps from the main_layout to the row layout .. that can't be confirmed from the trimmed layouts

Comment: @Zain which is why sharing the whole XML file for both views will clarify things.

Comment: The code was big, that's why I was replacing the unnecessary code with (...). Now I have updated both XML Codes, check it !!

Comment: If you are using min SDK version 29+ then you can debug this using layout manager.

Comment: I have fixed this issue now. I was changing visibility of Views but I have to change the visibility of there parents i.e., Swipe Refresh Layout which were overlapping. Thank You all!

Answer (score 1):

In the following part of your mainActivity xml File, you have two views that are basically on top of each other covering (almost) the whole screen.

```
<androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
    android:id="@+id/grid_view_swipe_refresh"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <GridView
        android:id="@+id/grid_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:paddingBottom="100dp"
        android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
        android:verticalSpacing="10dp"
        android:numColumns="2"
        android:visibility="invisible"/>

</androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>

<androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
    android:id="@+id/recycler_view_swipe_refresh"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:paddingBottom="100dp"
        android:clipToPadding="false"
        android:visibility="invisible"/>

</androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
```

since they are both invisible in the xml file, it means you are turning them visible in your code somewhere.

Now my guess is that you are turning both views `Visible` at the same time in your code but you are not assigning an adapter to the recyclerView, which practically means you have an empty (hence invisible) recycler view on top of your `GridView`.

Check for that please.

Comment: In my code only one view will be visible at a time. Check the above code, which I have updated, you will get to know. In recycler view there is also a button which works fine and everything is clickable in that recycler view but not in grid view.

Comment: I have fixed this issue now. I was changing visibility of Views but I have to change the visibility of there parents i.e., Swipe Refresh Layout which were overlapping. Thank You all!